# jqgrid delete: not getting value

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, jqgrid

I developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10).

I am using `JQGRID` to display data in tabular format. I also want functionality of Add, Edit, Delete in `JQGRID`. So far I have completed Edit Functionality.

Now I want `Delete` functionality, the problem is that I am not able to `pass data from JQGRID to servlet`.

Following is my source code:

```
jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid({
                height: "100%",
                url:'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?q=2&action=protStages',
                datatype: "xml",
                 colNames:['Sr. No.','PROTOCOL_ID',  'STAGE_ID',  'DESCRIPTION'],
                 colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true},
                           {name:'PROTOCOL_ID',index:'PROTOCOL_ID', width:100,sortable:false},
                           {name:'STAGE_ID',index:'STAGE_ID', width:100,sortable:false},
                           {name:'DESCRIPTION',index:'DESCRIPTION', width:150,sortable:false,editable:true}
                           ],
                rowNum:5,
                rowList:[2,4,10],
                pager: '#pager10_d2',
                sortname: 'PROTOCOL_ID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                multiselect: true,
                editurl: "ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageEdit",
                caption:"CRM_PROT_STAGES",
                onSelectRow: function(ids)
                {
                    if(ids && ids!==lastsel)
                    {               
                        var ret = jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('getRowData',ids);
                        protID = ret.PROTOCOL_ID;
                        alert(protID);
                        stageID = ret.STAGE_ID;
                        alert(stageID);

                        jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{}, {editurl:'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageEdit&protID='+protID+'&stageID='+stageID});
                        jQuery('#list10_d2').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
                        jQuery('#list10_d2').jqGrid('editRow',ids,true);
                        lastsel=ids;
                    }
                }
            });
            jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager10_d2',{add:true,edit:true,del:true},{width:500},{width:500,url: 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageAdd&protID='+protID, closeAfterAdd: true},{mtype: 'GET',url: 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageDelete&protID='+protID});
            jQuery("#ms1").click( function() {
                var s;
                s = jQuery("#list10_d2").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                alert(s);
            });
```

I am getting `protID` value `undefined` in my `DeleteServlet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `protID` in the `url` in the wrong way. The value of `url` option used for Delete operation will be set **once** during executing of the call of `navGrid`. At the moment you not yet set any value for the variable `protID`. You can fix the code you can use one from the following ways: `onclickSubmit`, `delData`, `beforeSubmit` or `serializeDelData`.

I am wounder a little that you use `mtype: 'GET'` option for delete operation. Typically one use HTTP POST or HTTP DELETE in the case. If you really need `mtype: 'GET'` you can replace

```
{
    mtype: 'GET',
    url: 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?action=protocolStageDelete&protID=' + protID
}
```

parameter of `navGrid` to

```
{
    mtype: 'GET',
    url: 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages',
    delData: {
        action: 'protocolStageDelete',
        protID: function () {
            return protID;
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively

```
{
    mtype: 'GET',
    url: 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages',
    onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
        var rowData = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
        return {
            action: 'protocolStageDelete',
            protID: ret.PROTOCOL_ID
        };
    }
}
```

If you do consider to use `mtype` other as `GET`, but will need to set `protID` as part of URL you can modify `url` option dynamically inside of `onclickSubmit` or `beforeSubmit` callback. For example

```
{
    mtype: 'GET',
    onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
        var rowData = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
        options.url = 'ProtocolJGridServChildStages?' + jQuery.param({
            action: 'protocolStageDelete',
            protID: ret.PROTOCOL_ID
        });
    }
}
```

You can choose yourself the way which better corresponds your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for explaining with alternatives.