# Sending EditData JQgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a project which uses jqgrid version 3.6.5. I have to add a field dynamically on popup form and send it along with posted data. I have searched it on the net but most of the results seem to be about version 4.*. we are at the stage that we cannot upgrade the jqgrid version. How can I send additional values in jqgrid 3.6.5?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 3.6.5 is really old (almost tree year old), but if already support the most important features which you could need.

To send additional information to the server on submitting of Add or Edit form you can

- use `editData` option
- use `onclickSubmit` to return object with additional information which will be appended to the standard data send to the server
- use `serializeEditData` option of jqGrid to implement custom serialization of data or to add additional information too.

So you can follow for example my advises from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195049/315935).

[The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745168/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020340/315935) show how to add any custom information in the edit form.