# inline delete - delOptions - how to add additional data to restful post?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm looking at this documentation and wonder how do you add additional restful POST data when submitting to the server then remove a jqgrid row when success but not remove row when failed.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow

I also saw this example but I'm not getting it on restful post.   [jqGrid (Delete row) - How to send additional POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833254/jqgrid-delete-row-how-to-send-additional-post-data)

Thanks...

```
formatter: 'actions', 
formatoptions: {
   keys: false, editbutton: false, 
   delOptions: {
       url: jqgridWebUrl, 
       mtype: 'POST', 
       ???
   }
}
```

Comment: How you want to have the URL? You use `mtype: 'POST'`, but write about [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST#RESTful_web_APIs) services which use HTTP DELETE. Which kind of data you need to send and in which way exactly?

Comment: I want to send additional restful data like this in HTTP POST method.  I'm not using HTTP DELETE method.  The value need to be like this -->  "WhichJqgridTemplate=Inventory&VehicleId=" $(this).getCell(rowid, 1) .  Thanks...

Comment: I saw that delData is one way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many way to do this. You can use `onclickSubmit`, use `beforeSubmit`, use `delData` or `serializeDelData`. All the options you should place inside of `delOptions`.

If you need modify `url` used during deleting you can use `onclickSubmit` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330854/315935) for code example). Other examples you would find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195049/315935).

Comment: delData doesn't seem to work as I cannot get rowid so I used onclickSubmit and it works great.  I'll post another question related to this one.  (I forgot one more thing to it).

Comment: @fletchsod: You can use `errorTextFormat` callback to customize error text.