# Two Parameter for Deleting A Row in JqGrid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jqgrid

I have some problem for deleting a row in jqGrid.

My row consists of two primary keys which are email and idms_module. These two keys are needed for deleting the row, because one email can have two or more idms_module.

Here's the syntax:

```
   jQuery("#grid-uac").jqGrid({
                mtype:'GET',
                url:'functions/get_useraccess.php',
                editurl:'functions/edit_useraccess.php',
                datatype: "JSON",
                colNames:['User Email','Module Access','Level Access'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'user_email', width:300, editable:true, key:true},
                    {name:'module_access', width:550,editable:true, key:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'functions/get_modusracc.php'}},
                    {name:'level_access',width:100,editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value:"0:read only;1:read write"}}
                ],
                loadComplete: function () {
                alert("OK");
                },    
                loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                          'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                          'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                    alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[5,10,15],
                pager: '#pager-uac',
                sortname: 'user_email',
                viewrecords: true,
                jsonReader: **{id: "user_email", id2 or some var : "module_access"}**, 
                sortorder: "asc",
                gridview: true,
                autoencode:true,
                caption:"Inventory User Access Role"
            });
```

So for example I want to delete a row, which consists of email: admin@test.com and idms_module: 6

The part of the php code is:

```
  $email  = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $modules= $_REQUEST['another var'];

  $query = DELETE FROM table WHERE email= $email AND module = $modules
```

I have successfully gotten the email from the id but haven't got any ideas on how to get the 'another var'

Comment: @Oleg is it possible to do like this? if not, i will use another way to delete the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all one common remark about the database design. Typically one use integer values in the database. One uses `IDENTITY` or `AUTO_INCREMENT` words during definition of such column. One uses the integer column as `PRIMARY KEY` typically. One adds additionally `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on the columns which can't contains duplicates. `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` adds index on the column so the searching by the column will be quickly. I think that all tables in the database which I used in productive databases follow the rule.

You you don't can to change anything on the server side then you can do the following. You can't use the property `key:true` in more as one column of `colModel`. You can't use it in one column like `user_email` if you can have more as one row which the same data. What you can do is for example: usage of composed `id` value which consist from `user_email`, `module_access` value and some separator. For example in case of `"test@mydomain.com"` and `"module1"` you can use `test@mydomain.com@module1` as the id. The second `@` can't be in e-mail any you can use it as separator. One more variant of encoding will be [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded (or just HEX encoded) value of `user_email`, the character `_` and Base64 encoded (or HEX encoded) value of `module_access`. jqGrid will send you the rowid during Delete operation and you will be able to decode the rowid to `user_email` and `module_access`.

One more option which you have is usage *any* rowid, but send both `'user_email'` and `'module_access'` together with the rowid. You can use `serializeDelData` or `onclickSubmit` callbacks (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2)) or you `delData` to extend the data. The callbacks get rowid as the input. You can use the `getCell` or `getRowData` to retry `'user_email'` and `'module_access'` and just extend the data which will be sent to the server. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16135162/315935) shows the same for Edit operation. Simple renaming of callbacks will show you the . Another examples you will find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195049/315935) or in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330854/315935).

Comment: hi @oleg, thanks for your answer, i've decided to change the way for deletion function. Because, i don't have rights to change the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can your server provide an additional data attribute consisting in email+id? You could then declare it as the id column (hidden) in jqgrid, and have the server untokenize it when you send it back?

Comment: hi @Pablo, what do you mean by additional data attribute? thanks